# configurable product price not change on product page

Tags: product, configurable-product, price

I have upload configurable product with different price. But i have select other size of my product so product price not change on product page any one resolve my problem. I have already create supper attribute but no solution.

Comment: Magento version ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use magento 1.9.3 version
in your theme you need to add product_option.js
go to your app/design/frontend/[Your package]/[Your default]/layout/catalog.xml

find catalog_product_view
and in reference name="head" add this line

```
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
```

its become like that:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">        
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
    </reference>
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
```

Comment: Can i get help regard configurable product price issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/291238/57334  @Rajan Soni